# Symfony - FormType - set field display:none by default

Tags: symfony, label, styles, field, display

in my formType on Symfony I try to hide a default field.

So I did like this:

```
        ->add('amountReduction', NumberType::class, [
            "required" => false,
            "label" => "Montant de la réduction",
            "attr" => [
                "style" => "width: 200px; display: none;"
            ],
        ])
```

The problem is that the label is still visible. I would like to display: none; the whole field by default.

The goal is then that in the template, I can make a `$(".field").show()` which will display the label and the entire field

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [row_attr](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#row-attr) option.

```
->add('amountReduction', NumberType::class, [
            "required" => false,
            "label" => "Montant de la réduction",
            "row_attr" => [
                "class" => "d-none"
            ],
        ])
```